# Apache rewriteRule url delete?

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I am trying to delete the `?` character in the URL, something like:

```
http://domain.com/test.ts/?Type=1  ->  http://domain.com/test.ts/Type=1
```

I've added the following configuration in the *httpd.conf* file:

```
RewriteEngine ON

RewriteRule ^ts/?$ ts/$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

but it is not working.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 RewriteRule "^test.ts/(.*)=(.*)$" "test.ts/?$1=$2"  [QSA,NC]
```

Comment: I try this but still not working,what i need is to delete the ? character after "ts/".

Comment: @babafall try it again, I made a change

Comment: in test,write this `http://domain.com/test.ts/Type=1`  directly, not `http://domain.com/test.ts/?Type=1` .  the first will work for you as the second. that's the point of apache rewriting.